# The scene of "Speak Your Language"

Tags: plot-explanation, dinner-for-schmucks

I do understand the joke about Volvo in *Dinner for Schmucks* since he mixed up Swedish and Sweden. However, what is it about the Language he is speaking (her def his a der turda purda purda pu)? Moreover, the army knife he is referring to and 'does the cheese come out of the cow with the holes?' means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's confusing *Sweden* with *Switzerland*. The knife is a [Swiss Army Knife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Army_knife), and the cheese is [Swiss cheese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_cheese) (notice the holes).

Additionally, the "language" is most likely a reference to the [Swedish Chef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_Chef) from the Muppets who spoke in a similarly ridiculous fashion.

Comment: Thank you . In addition , about  'does the cheese come out of the cow with the holes?' When he said Holes , what was he referring to , the cow or the cheese ?

Comment: The holes in the cheese. In other words, "does Swiss cheese come out of cows with the holes already in it?"